# Error : "Invalid argument","Code 0" on IE8 in Jquery

Tags: jquery, dom, stylesheet

I'm using Jquery in my project. Everything works good on Firefox, but on IE, I get error saying "Invalid argument","Code 0". I found that the line

```
$(thisObj).css({'border':'1px dotted transparent;'});
```

is causing problem.

Is there any other way to set the css ?

Also, in the same project, I'm using styleSheet object. I have completed the functionality and it works on Firefox. Now, While I tested on IE, I needed to change some property names to make it working. What can be the best way to make it working for IE also. Do I need to rewrite the functions for IE ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

i usually use `$(thisObj).css('border','1px dotted transparent');` syntax

Comment: It shouldn't matter - I think the object is traversed and ran as above under the hood.

Answer (score 1):

When using a setting call to [`.css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/#css2) you shouldn't include the trailing semi colon on the value, as you would in a normal bit of CSS.

```
$(thisObj).css({'border':'1px dotted transparent;'});
                                                |
                                      //remove this semi-colon

$(thisObj).css({'border':'1px dotted transparent'});
```

I've just quickly tested this on my work IE7 machine here, and adding a semi-colon to any `.css()` call of this nature instantly breaks it with the error message you are quoting.