# How do I fix `Internet Argument Code: 0` in Internet Explorer 8?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

i have this line somewhere in my JS file

```
while(this.c.offsetWidth > this.w - s && --exit){
   w = isNaN(this.cw[0])? this.w - s : --this.cw[0];
   if(w < 1 || this.w < Math.max(1, s)){break;}
   this.c.style.width = isNaN(this.cw[0])? this.w - s + 'px' : --this.cw[0] + this.cw[1];
  }
```

IE keeps telling me `Invalid Argument code:0`

but its working fine on other browsers (as expected from IE)

Comment: Right as it stands there, your JS is malformed - missing a `{`

Comment: Sorry , code edited , didn't copy the whole loop

Comment: @camus IE8 , and IE9 i guess (my friend says the error is reproduced there as well but i haven't confirmed it yet)

Comment: missing an `(` in front of your condition of the ternary op.

Comment: Try adding firebug lite to debug

Comment: Also I would encourage you, to avoid these in/decrementers wherever you can.

Comment: @RonanDejhero: Can you try to put up a JsFiddle with this so that we can try?

Comment: @Christoph: Nope, ternary operations do not require enclosing parentheses.

Comment: @TomWijsman i just overlooked the `isNan()`

Comment: full source of the script http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex2/crawler/index.htm

Comment: That script [just works for me](http://jsfiddle.net/GrkJf/) both on the source page as well as the jsFiddle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that the problem lies in this line:

```
this.c.style.width =
    isNaN(this.cw[0]) ? this.w - s + 'px' : --this.cw[0] + this.cw[1];
```

If you think carefully about what `this.c.style.width` is set to, you'll see that it would be set to different results. Exactly, in the former you use `'px'` but in the latter you don't. Obviously, one of them is right while the other is wrong...

[Here is another example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4204406/47064) where ending characters were the problem.

Comment: the isNaN is there actually to check that thing right ? i mean i did not build the code , here's the link for the source

Comment: @RonanDejhero: No, the isNaN checks whether it has been defined with a valid value. Depending on that the width can be set with 'px' and without 'px', one of them is wrong. Also, [it just works for me](http://jsfiddle.net/GrkJf/) so you might want to check what's different in your implementation...

Comment: my implementation had to do with the css , had to give the width a value without the 'px' otherwise the width were not set . commented the line that gave the error , everything works fine now . wondering what was that line for !

Answer (score 0):

Could it be an order of operations problem in your ternary? See the change below where I put parentheses around this.w - s to make sure that operation is performed before appending 'px':

```
this.c.style.width = isNaN(this.cw[0])? (this.w - s) + 'px' : --this.cw[0] + this.cw[1];
```